# ASP.NET deleting and creating new cookie when trying to retrieve a cookie

Tags: asp.net, cookies

Inside my HomeController where page requests are processed, I'm attempting to retrieve a value for a cookie.

```
public ActionResult Index() {         
        var userCook = Response.Cookies.Get("user");
        whatever = userCook.Value;
        return View();
    }
```

Simply trying to retrieve the cookie "user", which should have a value of "admin", causes the cookie to be deleted from the client and end up with a value of nothing.

Note I have also tried:

```
    public ActionResult Index() {         
        string userCook = Response.Cookies["user"].Value;
        return View();
    }
```

These both delete the cookie and recreate a new cookie with the name "user" despite there already being a cookie called user with a value.

Comment: You should be referring to Request instead of Response.

Comment: -_- @WiktorZychla Thanks, pretty silly mistake.